# Deny node access based on custom field value (Using Code)

Tags: nodes, hooks, users

I'm new in Drupal so please bare with me. I am looking to **restrict access** to the article node based on a **custom field value**. So if the custom field value is set to 1 then allow access for all user expected anonymous user. I have a custom field of '**special article**' and this has a Boolean values of 1 (true) and 0 (false). I have tried numerous ways of doing this and I can deny access to every **article node**, but I only want to do it on the articles where the '**special_article**' field is set to 1. This is what I have so far and it restricts all articles from displaying to the anonymous user.

```
    function mymodule_node_access_records($node) {

  $grants = array();
  if ($node->type === 'article' && $node->status) {
    $grants[] = array(
        'realm' => 'mymodule_myrealm',
        'gid' => 1,
        'grant_view' => 1,
        'grant_update' => 0,
        'grant_delete' => 0,
        'priority' => 0,
    );
  }

  return $grants;
}


/**
 * Implements hook_node_grants().
 */
function mymodule_node_grants($account, $op) {
  $grants = array();

  if (user_access('can view member articles', $account)) {
    $grants['mymodule_myrealm'][] = array(1);
  }

  return $grants;
}
```

I tried to add the following to the above ccode but that didn't work.

```
function mymodule_node_access_records($node) {

      $grants = array();
      if ($node->type === 'article' && $node->field_special_article['und'][0]['value'] == 1 && $node->status) {
        $grants[] = array(
            'realm' => 'mymodule_myrealm',
            'gid' => 1,
            'grant_view' => 1,
            'grant_update' => 0,
            'grant_delete' => 0,
            'priority' => 0,
        );
      }

      return $grants;
    }
```

If anyone can help me out with this I would be really grateful. Thanks

Edit: Just to clarify, I would like to achieve this using code in a custom module to understand Drupal development better. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Nodeaccess](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess).

> The upshot is, this module allows you to do things like 'node 123 can be viewed by authenticated users and edited by admin users and joeuser'. As an added bonus, update and delete permissions are separated, so you can make sure users with edit permissions cannot accidentally delete pages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to do this in my own custom module and not use a Drupal contrib module. Basically I want to understand the code behind this for developing Drupal themes. Thanks again though

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after changing my code a bit and republishing the content in Drupal (republishing the content was key!) this is what worked. I hope it helps someone at some point.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_access_records().
 */
       function mymodule_node_access_records($node) {
      $grants = array();
      if (array_key_exists('field_special_article', $node)) { 
      if (array_key_exists('und', $node->field_special_article)) { 
      if ($node->field_special_article['und'][0]['value'] == 1) {

            if ($node->type === 'article' && $node->status) {
              $grants[] = array(
                'realm' => 'mymodule_myrealm',
                'gid' => 1,
                'grant_view' => 1,
                'grant_update' => 0,
                'grant_delete' => 0,
                'priority' => 0,
              );
            }
          }
        }
      }

      return $grants;
    }


    /**
     * Implements hook_node_grants().
     */
    function mymodule_node_grants($account, $op) {
      $grants = array();

      if (user_access('can view special articles', $account)) {
        $grants['mymodule_myrealm'][] = array(1);
      }

      return $grants;
    }
```